# C# OData v2 return only filtered expanded entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, expand

i have the following classes on my Context

---

```
public class Alpha {
   public string UserID {get;set;}
   public User User {get;set;}
   public string BetaID {get;set;}
   public Beta Beta {get;set;}
}
public class Beta {
   public string UserID {get;set;}
   public User User {get;set;}
   public virtual List<Alpha> Alphas {get;set;}
}
```

and a B's web api controller that has the following method

```
[EnableQuery(MaxTop = 100000)]
public List<Beta> GetAll()
{
    return Query().Where(s=>s.UserID == "logedinUserID").ToList(); 
}
```

now the problem is that when a user uses the above method and adds &$expand=Alphas to the url, i want the expanded Alphas that are returned to him to be filtered by UserID. Meaning that i dont want the expanded list to contain all Alphas, but just those that belong to him (UserID = "hisID")

Answer (score 0):

I only see it by using query interceptors (there might be another direct approach).
Something like this:

```
[QueryInterceptor("Alpha")]
public Expression<Func<Entity,bool>> GetAll()
{
    // implement your logic and return the object

}
```

Comment: I have never heard of WCF data serives before your comment. To my understanding my Controller would need to extend DataService. Is that right?

Comment: Also, according to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37061426/odata-web-api-query-interceptor   QueryInteceptors are not allowed in web api OData